# have never done it / have never done this / have never done that

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the difference between these sentences or they  mean absolutely the same thing and they are interchangeable?

> I **have never done it** before.
>
> I **have never done this** before.
>
> I **have never done that** before.

Comment: "...Or **do** they mean the same thing and are they interchangeable?" No. You would only use _this_ while actually doing the action in question - 'this thing that I'm doing'. In this context _that_ is a more emphatic version of _it_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three will often be used more or less interchangeably by fluent speakers. As the comment by  Kate Bunting suggests:

> I have never done this before.

is most natural when the speaker is doing the thing at the moment of speaking.

> "I have never done this before", he said, climbing the steep hill near his home.

But it can also  be used when it immediately follows or precedes a description of the thing to be done, so that the speaker is in a sense putting him- or herself into the moment of doing the thing.

> "You want me to lie to a trusted friend", she objected, "but I have never done this before."

Many speakers and writes will, however, not attend to this nuance of meaning.